# Regex Match word if string doesn't contain another word

Tags: regex, string, pcre

I'm looking for a PCRE regex that will match up certain processes but only if the process doesn't contain a specific word.

The REGEX should match if the string contains 'udp' but not if the word 'vpn' occurs anywhere in the string.

```
Example:
    /root/sumcommand -x -y udp 
    MATCH 

    /root/sumcommand VPN udp 12 4 2
    NO MATCH

    /root/sumcommand -x -y udp VPN 2 4 52
    NO MATCH

    /root/sumcommand udp ocean tools 1 5 2
    MATCH
```

So it will always match where 'udp' occurs if said string does not contain the word 'vpn'. How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try the below lookaround based regex.

```
(?i)^(?!.*\bvpn\b).*\budp\b.*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sU1mJ4/1)

Comment: This is awesome! My only issue with it though is that it finds a match if 'vpn' is part of a longer word, which I really would like to avoid. E.g. `/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/tunnel1-udp.pid --cd /etc/openvpn --config tunnel1-udp.conf`

Comment: I updated your regex to `(?i)^(?!.*vpn\b).*\budp\b.*$` which would allow me to find words that end in VPN as well, which is what I need. Without your answer I wouldn't have gotten that, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily achieve that using `grep`:

```
grep "\budp\b" | grep -v "\bVPN\b"
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need this done with a PCRE regex operation only.